# Spring. How to connect to the database manually if an event occurs

Tags: java, database, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

In my application there are 2 modes: admin and user mode. I need to connect to the database only if the admin mode is enabled. To work with the database, I use Spring Data JPA, I chose postgre as the database.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Here`s my application.properties

```
    ## PostgreSQL
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/metrics
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=root
    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Is there some kind of opportunity in Spring to manually connect to the database if, for example, an event occurs or a condition works (like for example in my code below)?

```
public void start(String[] args) {

    if (args[0].equals("user")) {
        switch (args[1]) {
         //some action
        }

    }
    if (args[0].equals("admin")) {
         //some action
         //how to connect to db here?
    }
}
```

Comment: any specific reason why you can't do the same when the application is starting, this needs to be done once in lifetime of the application ?

Comment: Spring is managing your datasources. You can have different DS - and use them all, as you like. I would not open other Datasources outside of spring, when you are using spring

Comment: I do not want to connect to the database while the user’s mod is running, because this mode is launched on a computer that does not have this database. This causes an error stating that it fails to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has specific application events handling, see for more [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events)

```
public class JdbcEvent extends ApplicationEvent...
```

Pseudocode for listener:

```
public class JdbcEventListener implements ApplicationListener<JdbcEvent> {
    @Autowired
    DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties 

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomSpringEvent event) {
         if (!jdbcConnectionExists) {
             DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
             dataSourceBuilder.username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
             ...
             JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSourceBuilder.build());
         }
    }
}
```

**Updated**

Comment: can you explain how are you creating the JDBC template at runtime.

Comment: @dassum sorry for the delay. I updated my answer by code solution